# Запрет выделения ячейки в ListView. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Есть самый простой ListView в котором 1000+ записей. Мне нужно использовать это как список Items, чтобы Items не выделялись и при нажатии на стрелки не обводились рамочкой. IsEnable=false не подходит, т.к. должен работать скролл, а так же должны нажиматься кнопочки внутри Items. Вроде вопрос очень популярный, но решения я нормального не нашел. Сделал через событие сброс:

```
private void tracksList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tracksList.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Но остается пунктирная рамочка при нажатии на стрелки. Может есть какое свойство, где можно это отключить без самописных непонятных костылей?

Comment: Возьмите вместо `ListView` `ItemsControl`.

Comment: А как тогда сделать скролл в нем?

Comment: Понял, нужно обернуть все в ScrollViewer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397839/itemscontrol-missing-vertical-scrollbar

Comment: Именно так! Забыл об этом написать. Оформлю тогда ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы отключить фокус и выделение элементов, нужно перейти к более простому `ItemsControl`. Как выяснил сам автор вопроса, при этом отключается скроллинг, поэтому его [нужно добавить самостоятельно](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18397839/276994):

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ... />
</ScrollViewer>
```